# JDA Discord Add Reaction To Message

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I have problem when I try to add reaction to message send by the bot. Here is my code and the problem I get when I try to add reaction.

The idea is simple. Just a poll command send by the bot + add reaction to it like thumbs up and thumbs down for example :

" $poll This Is Example Poll " and after this poll got created, add the reactions

CODE -

```
    @Override
    protected void execute(CommandEvent event) {
        if (this.check(event)) {
            return;
        }

        var args = event.getArgs().trim();
        if (args.isEmpty()) {
            this.incorrectUsage(event);
            return;
        }

        var announcementFormat = this.getConfig().getMessages().get("pool-format")
                .replaceAll("%message", args);


        event.reply(announcementFormat);
        event.getMessage().addReaction("✔").queue();
    }
```

ERROR -

```
ERROR net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.RestAction - RestAction queue returned failure: [ErrorResponseException] 10008: Unknown Message
net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.ContextException
        at net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.ContextException.here(ContextException.java:54)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.Request.<init>(Request.java:71)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.RestActionImpl.queue(RestActionImpl.java:197)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.RestAction.queue(RestAction.java:563)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.RestAction.queue(RestAction.java:529)
        at cf.lionsquad.lionminus.command.impl.PollCommand.execute(PollCommand.java:48)
        at com.jagrosh.jdautilities.command.Command.run(Command.java:323)
        at com.jagrosh.jdautilities.command.impl.CommandClientImpl.onMessageReceived(CommandClientImpl.java:557)
        at com.jagrosh.jdautilities.command.impl.CommandClientImpl.onEvent(CommandClientImpl.java:445)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handleInternally(EventManagerProxy.java:82)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:69)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:150)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.MessageCreateHandler.handleInternally(MessageCreateHandler.java:122)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:36)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:948)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:835)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:813)
        at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:986)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:385)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:276)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:996)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:755)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** You have to wrap the emoji using `Emoji.fromUnicode` in JDA 5. So the new code is `message.addReaction(Emoji.fromUnicode("✔"))`.

---

You can use [flatMap](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)):

```java
event.getChannel().sendMessage(announcementFormat)
     .flatMap(message -> message.addReaction("✔"))
     .queue();
```

Instead of `event.reply(announcementFormat)`.

Your code currently tries to add a reaction to the message sent by the user rather than the message sent by your bot. However, that message was already deleted at that point which is why you get an `Unknown Message` error.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the idea but how can I add like 2 reactions ???

Comment: I tried with a lot of things, nothing worked, one of them is :

" .flatMap(message -> message.addReaction("✔"), message -> message.addReaction("emoji")) "

not working :/

Comment: Try using RestAction.allOf(action1, action2)

Comment: Where I need to put this rest action ?

Comment: I tried with " .flatMap(RestAction.allOf(event.getMessage().addReaction("✔"),event.getMessage().addReaction("✔"))) " , not working.

Comment: Can you help me with this ? I'll be very glad.